# A topological space is extremally disconnected iff every two disjoint open sets have disjoint closures

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Show that for any topological space $X$ the following are equivalent:
>
> - $X$ is extremally disconnected
> - Every two disjoint open sets in $X$ have disjoint closures.

**My attempt at a solution**

Assume every two disjoint open sets in $X$ have disjoint closures.
Let A open in $X$, $A$ and $X \setminus \overline{A} $  disjoint open set
$\overline{A} \cap (\overline{X \setminus \overline{A}} )= \emptyset$,

$(\overline{X \setminus \overline{A}} ) \subset X \setminus \overline{A}$,
which implies that $X \setminus \overline{A}$ is closed in $X$. Thus $\overline{A}$ is open in $X$. So we obtain $X$ is extremally disconnected.

Otherwise Let $X$ is extremally disconnected. Then the closure of every open set is open.
 So $X$ is completely separated. Let $A$, $B$ two disjoint open sets.  Then there exist a continuous function $g:X \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that  $g(A)=0$, $g(B)=1$

How can I continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first half of your argument is fine. For the second half you don’t need the function $g$. You have the disjoint open sets $A$ and $B$. If $x\in B$, then $B$ is an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $A$, so $x\notin\operatorname{cl}A$. Thus, $B\cap\operatorname{cl}A=\varnothing$. Now suppose that $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$; $\operatorname{cl}A$ is open, so it’s an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $B$, and $x\notin\operatorname{cl}B$. It now takes just one small step to finish the argument to show that $(\operatorname{cl}A)\cap\operatorname{cl}B=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the open set $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$.  Is it possible for it to meet $A$?